# How to count similar files in hdfs by groovy code?

Tags: hadoop, groovy

I want to  count   files   with  similar   filenames  in   hdfs   directory, but  i  don't  want  to  use  File System  API can   you  recommend  me  something  which  can   help me  get  the  result   which  i  can   get  from this   groovy  code  below?

Is  there  any  equivalent  of file System Api  which   can  i  use   for   this  task?

```
String  filename="2017-02-03";
def count = new File("file   path ").listFiles()
            .findAll { it.name.substring(0,10) ==filename}
            .size();
```

Comment: What is happening with above code?

Comment: it  makes  list  of  file  in  dierectory and  then  counts amount  of  filename  which  first  10  symbol is 2017-02-03

Comment: I want to  make   same  with  hdfs   directory  files , can   you recommend me  something in this case

Comment: You have to use the Filesystem API